# pause process during lockscreen

Tags: scripts, lock-screen

I used [WhatPulse](http://whatpulse.org/) back on windows and got it installed on Ubuntu, too, but now sometimes, when waking up from standby, it expects an internet connection immediately and builds up a lot of ram and freezes my system pretty rapidly. This is a known bug. I didn't check or the last months for updates, but to learn something let me ask:

How can I pause this process during the lockscreen active? Maybe also: How can I watch the resources it uses and kill it when exceeding a certain memory limit?